# Creating Map Custom Visual in Power BI

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I'm in the early stages of creating a Power BI custom map visual. At the moment, I'm just trying to get a blank U.S. map to display. I'm using GeoJSON data, which I've added to my package as follows:

- Saved the JSON into a JavaScript file and added `var jsonData = {}` around it.
- Added this JavaScript file to a geojson subfolder to my node_modules folder
- Added an additional ExternalJS reference to my manifest - `"node_modules/geojson/us-states.js"`

Now I'm starting to build the visual as follows:

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    "use strict";
    export class Visual implements IVisual {
        private host: IVisualHost;
        private svg: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
        private div: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
        private container: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
        private json = JSON.parse((<any>window).jsonData);  

        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {

            this.svg = d3.select(options.element)
            .append('svg');
            this.container = this.svg.append("g")
                    .classed('container', true);
        }


        public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
            let width: number = options.viewport.width; 
            let height: number = options.viewport.height;

            // D3 Projection
            var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])    // translate to center of screen
                   .scale(1000);          // scale things down so see entire US

// Define path generator
            var path = d3.geo.path()               // path generator that will convert GeoJSON to SVG paths
                .projection(projection);  // tell path generator to use albersUsa projection

//Create SVG element and append map to the SVG
            this.svg.attr({
                width: width,
                height: height
            });

            this.svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(this.json.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .style("stroke", "#fff")
                .style("stroke-width", "1")
        }
    }
}
```

The visual is blank. No errors in console. I had hoped to debug using this: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/how-to-guide/how-to-debug/ , but the code provided there produced numerous errors and I believe has been deprecated based on a comment on that page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you added data into data buckets? Without dataset Power BI doesn't call update method of the visual.

Try to check the DOM tree of the visual to be sure that svg element or path was created after executing update method of the visual.